# Pedagogical notes on line bundles on complex projective manifolds

Tags: teaching, ag.algebraic-geometry, line-bundles

I would like to find some notes (or book), that explains on a very basic level what is a line bundle on a complex projective manifold. Maybe even, what is a line bundle on  $\mathbb CP^n$.  It seems to me that in a "usual" algebro-geometric approach line bundles come quite late, only after one defines what is a sheaf, ect. I wonder if this  can be explained in "quicker" way?

Comment: Sure, there are many places that discuss vector bundles without sheaves. "Characteristic Classes" by Milnor and Stasheff is one excellent book. There's also "Principles of Algebraic Geometry" by Griffiths and Harris.

Comment: Artie, I find Griffiths-Harris too difficult. Milnor and Stasheff, of course is great, but this is only topology :)

Comment: aglearner: it's true that Milnor and Stasheff is "only topology", but I still think it can be very useful in understanding vector bundles in algebraic geometry. By the way, I think Shafarevich's book Basic Algebraic Geometry has a pretty down-to-earth discussion of line bundles and vector bundles (and how they relate to sheaves), but maybe you've already seen that too.

Answer (score 3):

For a slightly different approach, I recommend *Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces* by Rick Miranda. This book starts out by developing everything in terms of divisors, then turns to line bundles and sheaves. I recommend it precisely because it works at developing lots of motivation for the notion of a sheaf (as well as that of sheaf cohomology).

Answer (score 2):

If you want complex vector bundles (or even complex fiber bundles) presented at a "very basic level" (without sheaf theory), try Chapter IV of

Fritzsche, Klaus; Grauert, Hans: From holomorphic functions to complex manifolds. Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 213. Springer-Verlag, New York, 2002. xvi+392 pp. ISBN: 0-387-95395-7

Answer (score 1):

I think there are several good references. For instance:

R. O. Wells: *Differential Analysis on complex manifolds* (Springer GTM **65**), Chapter III.

J. D. Moore: *Lectures in Seiberg-Witten invariants* (Springer LNM **1629**), Chapter 1.

D. Huybrechts: *Complex Geometry - An introduction* (Springer Universitext), Chapter 2.